# How to align button automatically

Tags: android, layout

I want my radio button to align automatically without specifying dp, how to do that?

In the below sample example, Radio button width 80 and height 70 is set. Instead i want to do this like fill_parent or wrap_content. How can i do?

```
<RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:checkedButton="@+id/allcontacts" 
      android:id="@+id/contactgroup">
      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/allcontacts" 
       android:width="80dip" 
       android:height="70dip"/>

      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/categories" 
       android:width="80dip" android:height="70dip" />

      <RadioButton android:id="@+id/favourites" 
        android:width="80dip" android:height="70dip" />
```

Comment: Instead of applying fixed size, apply `wrap_content`.

Comment: Instead of just saying "I want to align".. say how you want it aligned...

Comment: I want all these buttons to be aligned horizontally with equel spacing. I want this without specifying height and width in dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the buttons in a LinearLayout (horizontal) with a layout_width of match_parent.

For each button set the layout_height to wrap_content, set the layout_width to 0dp and set layout_weight to 1 and they will all be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a LinearLayout around the buttons. then you can use padding to adjust the exact location if needed

Comment: So, you mean to say, put these buttons in a lenear layout?

Comment: ya.wrap the linear layout inside the whole button you use.you did not mention what type you align your button,either horizontal or vertical.